# How to add value on URL using <a href> when it got clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, href, dom-manipulation

so I have four links with different Href for example

```
<a href="markmendoza.com/123">
<a href="markmendoza.com/555">
<a href="markmendoza.com/666">
<a href="markmendoza.com/999">
```

and I wanted to manipulate the href when it got clicked by adding some more value

when it get click it will be:

```
    markmendoza.com/123/?Sample
    markmendoza.com/555/?Sample
    markmendoza.com/666/?Sample
    markmendoza.com/999/?Sample
```

I got here my code

```
    let a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
     for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.target.href = event.target.href + '/?Sample';
      }
```

its adding fine but once you click it many times it just adds the **/?Sample** on the end of the link again and again so if I clicked the link 10x it will be **markmendoza.com/123/?Sample?Sample?Sample?Sample?Sample?Sample?Sample**

Comment: How is that? Shouldn't the link load a new page ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to add it once guard it’s with an if statement like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (!event.target.href.includes('/?Sample')) { //add this
            event.target.href = event.target.href + '/?Sample';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about the includes thank you!

Comment: its working but i'm getting an error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined do you know why this happens?

Comment: Can you man another question with a code snippet as well as the stack trace of the error? It’s hard to say, it usually happens when href property does not exist. Are you perhaps redirecting the user on click?

Comment: i did check it out and yes the property seems to be empty i fixed it now thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
jQuery.each( links, function( a, val ) {
  a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    link_href = event.target.href || ''
    if(!link_href.includes('/?Sample') {
      event.target.href = link_href + '/?Sample';
    }
  }
});
```